# How to render a list according to the checkbox selection?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a list that renders some products, these products are divided into some categories.

I am trying to apply a filter with these categories through checkboxes. When the user selects the checkbox, the list must be updated with the selected category.

I would like to know how to render a list of products according to the checkbox selection?

I put my code into [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-mendel-i1ipe?file=/src/App.js) because has a lot of files.

For example, here I would like to render only products from the `Chypre` and `Floriental` categories.

[image]

Here I render my list of products:

```js
import React, { useState, useMemo, useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

import CardItem from "../CardItem";
import Pagination from "../Pagination";
import Search from "../Search";
import { useStyles } from "./styles";

const Card = (props) => {
  const { activeFilter } = props;
  const classes = useStyles();
  const data = useSelector((state) => state.perfume.collections);
  const [searchPerfume, setSearchPerfume] = useState("");
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [perfumesPerPage, setPerfumesPerPage] = useState(3);

  console.log("activeFilter: ", activeFilter);

  const orderList = data
    .map((item) => ({
      ...item,
      totalSize: item.sizes.reduce((sum, cur) => sum + cur.price, 0)
    }))
    .sort((a, b) => a.totalSize - b.totalSize);

  const filteredPerfumes = useMemo(() => {
    return orderList.filter((perfume) =>
      perfume.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchPerfume.toLowerCase())
    );
  }, [orderList, searchPerfume]);

  const currentPerfumes = filteredPerfumes.slice(
    (currentPage - 1) * perfumesPerPage,
    currentPage * perfumesPerPage
  );
  const pages = Math.ceil(filteredPerfumes.length / perfumesPerPage);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentPage > pages) {
      setCurrentPage(1);
    }
  }, [currentPage, pages]);

  const pageNumbers = Array(pages)
    .fill(null)
    .map((val, index) => index + 1);

  const handleClick = (page) => {
    setCurrentPage(page);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Search
        data-testid="input-filter-id"
        setSearchPerfume={setSearchPerfume}
      />
      {currentPerfumes
        .filter((perfume) => {
          return (
            perfume.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchPerfume.toLowerCase()) >= 0
          );
        })
        .map((item) => (
          <CardItem key={item.id} item={item} />
        ))}
      <Pagination
        pageNumbers={pageNumbers}
        handleClick={handleClick}
        currentPage={currentPage}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Card;
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try that one

```
 const filteredPerfumes = useMemo(() => {
    const filtered = orderList.filter((perfume) =>
      perfume.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchPerfume.toLowerCase())
    );

    if (activeFilter.length > 0) {
      return filtered.filter((item) => item.categories.some((a) =>
        activeFilter.some((v) => v.text === a)
      ));
    }
    return filtered;
  }, [orderList, searchPerfume]);
```

Comment: Hey Oyeme, This worked for me, thank you very much !!! One more thing, when I select two categories at once, the list is empty. Do you know how to fix this? Thanks again.

Comment: sure, I have updated my code. Just replace activeFilter.every to activeFilter.some

Comment: Thanks Oyeme, but when I changed activeFilter.every to activeFilter.some my list don't render.

Comment: I updated my code for you see: https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-dijkstra-1tflo?file=/src/features/components/Card/Card.jsx

Comment: I can't create more than 3 sandboxes, but I have updated my code. Just paste it. The reason why you couldn't see the default list because activeFilter was empty. Pelase see the code above.

Comment: first of all, you need to check if you have any filters, then you can apply extra filtering.

Comment: Now I understand, everything worked perfectly here. Thank you so much again Oyeme.